# Mongo DB update with expire

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ttl

My new entrys of the unlock schema don't get deleted after 60 seconds.
I executed this in the Mongodb shell:

```
db.unlocks.ensureIndex( { "createdAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 60 } )
```

This is my Schema:

```
var unlocker = new Schema({createdAt: { type: Date},_id: String, code: String,unlock: Boolean});
```

Here i add my entrys:

```
unlock.update({_id:''+ip+''},{createdAT: new Date(),code: ''+code+'',unlock: false},  {upsert:true}...
```

They should expire but they dont.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a typo in your code:

```
unlock.update({_id:''+ip+''},{createdAT: new Date() ...
```

should be

```
unlock.update({_id:''+ip+''},{createdAt: new Date() ...
```